# Foreign storage of a carry-on

Tags: international-travel, hand-luggage, luggage-storage, vancouver

I am going on my first international flight to backpack solo near Vancouver, Canada. I would like to keep my pack as light as possible when I get to the trail head, while keeping a set of clean clothes for later. I think a carry-on that I can access at the end of my hike would be best, but I have no place safe to store this additional bag.

Is there something like a locker available in the Vancouver International Airport? Are there other options?

I plan on doing more trips similar to this one, are storage options common for International Airports around the world?

Comment: Google is your friend: searching "Vancouver airport luggage storage" pointed immediately to http://www.cdsbaggage.ca/.  You'll have to call for prices.  Note there is a good chance it'll be expensive.

Comment: @NateEldredge That smells of an answer rather than a comment

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79359/luggage-storage-luggage-check-details-at-vancouver-bc-train-station

Comment: @NateEldredge do add your comment as an answer; it's spot on. Ping me and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Since I don't have any first-hand knowledge of this business, and I don't feel like calling them for more information, I'd rather not post it as an answer.  If someone else wants to do so, they may feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found by @NateEldredge through a Google search, CDS Ltd. has baggage storage in two locations in Vancouver International Airport (YVR):

- International Terminal (before Security) Level 2, 05:00 - 01:00 Daily
- Domestic Terminal (before Security) Level 2, 05:00 - 23:00 Daily

A subsequent Google search for luggage storage in Vancouver returns these businesses:

- [PorterGenie](https://www.portergenie.com/)
- [BagBnB](https://bagbnb.com/luggage-storage/vancouver)
- [Lugler](https://www.lugler.com/luggage-storage/vancouver/)